# Is my DAO strategy ok?

Tags: java, hibernate, dao

I'm using Hibernate. The question is at the bottom.

## The current strategy

It's simple.

First of all, I have a basic `Dao<T>`.

```
public class Dao<T> {
    private Class<T> persistentClass;
    private Session session;

    public Dao(Class<T> persistentClass) {
        this.persistenClass = persistentClass;
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
    }
```

It's nice as a base class and it passes the most common methods up to its `Session`.

```
    public T get(Serializable id) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T t = (T) this.session.get(this.persistentClass, id);

        return t;
    }

    protected Criteria getCriteria() {
        return this.session.createCriteria(this.persistentClass);
    }
```

When there's need to use queries on the model, it goes into a specific DAO for that piece of model, which inherits from `Dao<T>`.

```
public class DaoTask extends Dao<Task> {
    public DaoTask() {
        super(Task.class);
    }

    public List<Task> searchActiveTasks() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Task> list = (List<Task>) this.getCriteria()
            .add(Restrictions.eq("active", true))
            .list();

        return list;
    }
}
```

This approach has always worked well.

### However...

However, today I found that many times an instance needs reattachment to the `Session` and a line similar to the following ends up happening:

```
new Dao<Book>(Book.class).update(book);
```

... which I find to be bad, because

1. I don't like specifying the redundant `Book.class`
2. If ever a `DaoBook` arises, this construct will become obsolete.

So I turned `Dao<T>` into an abstract class, and went on to refactor the old code.

## Question

In order to remove the `Dao<T>` references from the codebase, I thought of two approaches:

1. Create specific DAOs for every class that ever needs attachment, which would generate many almost empty `DaoBook`s and the sort.
2. Create a class that owns a `Dao<Object>` and exposes only the attachment methods (i.e. `save()`, `update()` etc).

I'm tending to go with #2, but I thought this "`AttacherDao`" pattern might be bad, so I'd like your opinion.

Any cons for #2? Also, do you find anything wrong with "the current strategy"?

Answer (score 1):

Our approach is to have a DAO object (derived from a commonDao) for each persistent class. In fact we define interface for this DAO class and each DAO decides which interfaces are opened up.

Using the following code, user cannot delete the `PersistentClass`.

```
interface PersistentClassDao {
    void save(PersistentClass persistentObject);    
}

Class PersistentClassDaoImpl extends CommonDao implements PersistentClassDao {
        void save(persistentObject) {
    persist(persistentObject);
}
```

Even though it has some additional overhead, this approach helps in unit testing appropriate code before exposing an interface.

Comment: So your suggestion is to have an interface to each "business operation", ie DeletableClassDao, UpdatableClassDao etc?

Comment: No. There will be only one DAO for a business object not for a business operation, e.g. BookDao and BookDao will encapsulate all operations on Book object and can decide whether users can "save", "update" and/or "delete".

Answer (score 0):

Couple of questions

1. Are you frequently creating your DAO to do a single task or are these long lived?
2. What about using a static function? Clearly your Book object can be bind the DAO function to  without the Book.class reference...

Otherwise, I'm a little worried about keeping the session object around instead of fetching whatever the current session is - isn't it considered "bad" to have long lived session objects? I'm not a master of DAO, so maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: DAOs are short-lived. Sessions are open just as long as the user request is being processed.

Comment: DAO. DOA is when something bad has happened ;)

Answer (score 0):

We've chosen an approach similar to lud0h's, with the following twist:

```
abstract class<T extends IModelObject> JdbcCrudDao<T>{

   void create(T dbo){}
   T findByFoo(String foo){}
   void update(T dbo){}
   void delete(T dbo){}

}

class BarDao extends JdbcCrudDao<Bar>{

}
```

But, the twist is that we selectively expose methods on the Dao through a facade and forward only those we absolutely must.

```
class BarController implements IController{

    private static final BarDao dao;
    // ...

    void update( IBar bar ){
       dao.update(bar);
    }

}
```

The only short-coming in all this is it requires some casting about if you wish to hide your database keys behind an interface type (which we do), but it's a pretty minor inconvenience versus the alternative (database code outside of the Daos).

Comment: I think your brevity confused things for me. Does JdbcCrudDao implement anything or are those really empty or abstract methods? Same for BarDao!